# Add a date prefix on mysql id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, auto-increment, prefix

I have an ID field that i would like it to have the following format:
YYMMDDXXXXXXXX where YY is the year, MM the month, DD the day and XXXXXXXX is the actual ID number with leading zeroes.Also the ID number should reset to 0 when the day changes.

First, is this a not so good practise/format for an ID field thats also going to be a primary key?

Implementation:

I'm inserting data to my database threw php, i came up with 2 ways to achieve the said format.

- Inserting it manual with the php insert query(no AUTO_INCREMENT on the
  field), i select the MAX(id), split it(date-id), check if the day has
  changed and then either just increment it by one or replace it by
  newdate+0s. The problem with this way is that i have to do an extra
  SELECT and check/change the string, SELECT may return the same MAX(id) if i have more than 20
  requests/sec and also `date('Ymd')` causes the apache to crash for
  more than 60 requests/sec.
- Adding AUTO_INCREMENT on the ID field and set the AUTO_INCREMENT on
  YYMMDD00000000 when the day changes, then letting the auto_increment
  do the job. I tried `ALTER TABLE foo
  AUTO_INCREMENT=(SELECT CURDATE()*100000000)` but as i expected CURDATE() can't
  be used like this.

Any ideas and/or help on my tries would be great, thanks for your time.

Comment: you should split this data into two columns

Comment: I already have a date column, but i also need to have it stored as a prefix on the id column.

Comment: @tsta Why? We can't tell if there's a real justification here, if it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), or if it's something that can be solved more efficiently a different way. Right now all that's visible is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The sane way:

1. Tell your team manager that this design is massively flawed.
2. Present the following schema instead:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE foo (
     id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
     date DATETIME DEFAULT=NOW(),
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     INDEX (date)
   );
   ```
3. If necessary generate a similarly-styled ID with the query:

   ```
   SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m%d') AS UNSIGNED)*100000000 + id AS 'weird_id'
   ```

   Though this will go off the rails if your IDs become > 10,000,000, though my testing shows that using a BIGINT for this sheme should be able to handle one or two more zeroes. You can also get around the integer type limitations by selecting this ID as a string, eg:

   ```
   SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d'), LPAD(id,10,'0')) AS 'weird_id'
   ```

   Where `10` in the `LPAD()` can be as many digits as you want.

#### The not-sane, face-saving, future-nightmare-causing way:

You almost had it. `CURDATE()` returns a string, and `ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT=` expects an integer and nothing but an integer. No functions, variables, etc. The following will work:

bash:

```
mysql -u root -e "ALTER TABLE dbname.foo AUTO_INCREMENT = $(date +%Y%m%d0000000000);"
```

PHP:

```
$query = sprintf("ALTER TABLE dbname.foo AUTO_INCREMENT = %s;", str_pad(date("Ymd", time()), 18, '0'));
```

This will break:

- Whenever crond hiccups
- Probably during daylight savings time changes
- Randomly and for no apparent reason
- After midnight on December 31, 9999

Do yourself, and whoever inherits this project from you, a favor and keep a separate `DATETIME` column in this table so that meaningful, not-broken info can still be gleaned from it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for using your time in order to help me, i tried your last query to change the `AUTO_INCREMENT` but i still get the same error i had with my query, starting right after the '=' symbol.
We allready have an other column for a separate timestamp,is there any actual difference if the variable type is text instead of date/time?
Also, are there any other possible side effects for changing the `AUTO_INCREMENT` so frequently on a quite large table?

Comment: @tsta Apparently MySQL doesn't like anything other than an integer in there, I've update my answer. As for the performance concerns, there should not be any. All the `ALTER` does is change a value in the table's metadata. Just be sure to never change the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to a *lower* value.